# XPath with multiple values for same element

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm writing an XPath to query into a XML file with the following structure

```
<products>    
<product>
   <id></id>
   <categories>
       <category>38</category>
       <category>41</category>
       <category>43</category>
   </categories>
</product>
</products>
```

I was able to get products matching ids 41 OR 43 like this

```
products/product[categories/category[. = '43' or . = '41']]
```

I need to get products matching both ids 41 & 43 and this doesn't work

```
products/product[categories/category[. = '43' and . = '41']]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no category that is both 41 and 43 at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
products/product[
    categories[category='43']
              [category='41']
]
```

`product` with `categories` containing both `category` 43 and `category` 41